# How to extend (alter) webform submit function to add more funcitionality?

Tags: 7, webforms, forms

I have created a webform, whose id is `webform_client_form_1`, I have 3 fields:

> Name:
>   Email:
>   Phone number:

Now I want to extend webform submit function to send SMS to that `Phone number`. I have a working PHP script which sends SMS, using 3rd party service.

So my question is **how to extend the submit function for webform?** **Is there any hook available or there is other method to do it?**

Submit function for webform is: `webform_client_form_submit`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just append your function to the `#submit` element to add it to the list of handlers.

```
MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'webform_client_form_1') {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'webform_client_form_submit';
  }
}
```

Comment: didn't know we can add multiple submit handler :) thanks for saving my day.

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner solution would be to implement [hook_webform_submission_insert](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21webform%21webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_insert/7). This let's you do it using a native webform hook rather than hacking the form directly.

```
function MYMODULE_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission) {
  if ($node->nid == 123) {
    // send sms if node id is the one you wanted
  }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for solution something like this, but seems like this function is called after submission is saved in database. so I guess `Shawns` solution works better in my case, please enlighten me if I have missed anything here :)

Comment: Your question did not specify that you wanted to send the sms before the submission was saved to the db. If that's important just use hook_webform_presave instead.